# Diferencia entre alertDialogStyle y alertDialogTheme

Tags: android, alertdialog

Bueno el titulo es muy claro, ¿cual es la diferencia entre **alertDialogStyle** y **alertDialogTheme**?

He estado mirando en la documentación de **Android developers** pero no me queda muy claro,¿me lo podríais explicar mejor?

```
<resources>
    <style name="PLMS_Style" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyToolbar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTheme">@style/MyToolbar</item>
    </style>
    <style name="MyToolbar">
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/primary_text_material_dark</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondaryInverse">@color/secondary_text_material_light</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

¿En este caso que tendría que utilizar, Style o Theme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta pregunta es interesante, sería adecuado un titulo como

### "Diferencia entre Style y Theme".

[Styles y Themes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) es aplicado no solo para un [AlerDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html), se aplica a cualquier tipo de vista, TextView, EditText, Button, ImageView, etc...

> **Style**: (en español "Estilo"), es una colección de propiedades tales como colores, fuentes, efectos, tamaños, background, etc. que
>   definen el aspecto de una vista.

```
<TextView
    style="@style/myStyle"
    android:text="Hola StackOverflow.com" />
```

> **Theme**: (en español "Tema"), A diferencia de Style, el Theme es aplicado a toda la Activity, no únicamente a una vista, por lo tanto las propiedades son
>   heredadas a las vistas que contiene la Activity, todos los elementos que se contengan adoptaran el `Style` definido por el `Theme`.

```
<activity  android:name="MainActivity"
android:theme="@style/myTheme">
```

En el caso de Android el `theme` puede ser aplicado a todas las Activities de tu aplicación.

```
  <application
        android:label="Stackoverflow.con app"
        android:theme="@style/myTheme">
```

---

Ejemplo definiendo un `Theme` para AlerDialog:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle);
builder.setTitle("my AlertDialog");
builder.setMessage("Hola StackOverflow.com!");
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
builder.show();
```

donde `MyAlertDialogStyle` es:

```
<style name="MyAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <!-- Used for the buttons -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#AACC12</item>
    <!-- Used for the title and text -->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
    <!-- Used for the background -->
    <item name="android:background">#12AAF1</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Me ha dejado bastante claro lo que me has dicho... pero tengo una pregunta más, si yo me creo un tema para mi app en la carpeta Res, tengo la posibilidad de añadir las propiedades por ejemplo de  AlertDialogTheme y AlertDialogStyle, la correcta seria añadir la propiedad tema, la de estilo seria inútil utilizarla no ?

Comment: borjis, agregue a mi respuesta un ejemplo de como utilizar un Style en tu AlertDialog, como puedes ver defines el AlertDialog y le configuras un Style, en el caso de que definas un Theme el Theme tiene implícitamente relacionado un Style, por ejemplo   <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/dialog</item>. Es correcto lo que comentas he visto que se define AlertDialogTheme  y AlertDialogStyle pero en realidad si defines el AlertDialogTheme  no necesitas agregar el AlertDialogStyle.